# how to properly order_by(time) in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

How do I do the order_by part in codeigniter?

```
SELECT <field> FROM <table> ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE( <field>,  '%H:%i' ) DESC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Tried this but it takes "`'%H:%i')`" as the field name.

```
$this->db->order_by("STR_TO_DATE(".$field.", '%H:%i')", $order);
```

The field is a varchar and the query I posted returns the result that I want but I don't know how to do it in codeigniter

Comment: After testing a few things, it looks like the `,` comma triggers CI to wrap the wrong part in backticks: `STR_TO_DATE(last_login, \`'%H:%i')\``. MySQL functions are always such a pain to use with Codeigniter's Active Record.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that in CodeIgniter in version 2.1.0. As Madmartigan put it, the comma trigger CI to wrap the wrong part in the backticks and thus giving the mysql error. I think there is no point digging into active record on the `order_by` function to find a workaround than a real fix for this to work. I check into the upstream and apparently, they have something which is [interesting](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/commit/2c685fb03a4d4b5a96789b839147191ce8cffacc), you might want to keep an eye when is that released.

I didn't spend more time to find workaround in active record `order_by` but resort to this alternative which seem to work fine. Consider the following?

```
$sql = "SELECT <field> FROM <table> ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(?, '%H:%i') desc LIMIT 0, 30";
$this->db->query($sql, array('19:20'));
```

Comment: That's funny, I randomly came back to check on this question and you posted not a minute before. I agree with you not to fight against CI's AR and just use "normal" SQL, although it might be easy enough to write this function into it.

Comment: True, let's get the functioning part work first before improve it further. I think the next release from CI, the additional parameter for the order_by is something worth to look into it by the OP.